# How to execute make rule based on change/update in prerequisite timestamp?

Tags: makefile

I have listed few files into a variable BUILD ,then at my make rule i have given this variable as prerequisite. I have executed this make rule first time it executed that rule. i again executed the same make file without changing any prerequisite for that rule, at second execution, it should not execute that rule and should display a message "gmake: Nothing to be done for `Rule'." This rule is being executed all the time though there is no change in the prerequisites.

make file :

```
BUILD = \  
D:/Build/PeGen/\*.exe \  
D:/Build/PWrGen/\*.dll \

All:c1

c1: $(BUILD)
    cd D:/Mo/Ap/Po/Co/Ts/Build && \  
    "$(MAKE)" -s -f Build2.mk
```

Comment: Is the empty line before the recipe intentional?

Comment: no it is not , not able to remove here, but in actual make file there is no empty line.just found a solution using touch command, trying to create the target with rule title. just implemented , need to check the results. .............. at the end of the recipe added @touch c1 command ... build is going on need to check . will this be useful?

Comment: The default goal is `All`. Do you have a file named `All`? If not, make will try to build it. You told make that `All` depends on `c1`. Again, do you have a file named `c1`? If not, make will try to build it. It is only if a file named `c1` exists already that make will check whether it is older or newer than its prerequisites to decide if it must rebuild it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule for `c1` target probably doesn't create that target file. Hence, `make` needs to build that target.

One possible fix:

```
c1: $(BUILD)
    "$(MAKE)" -s -C D:/Mo/Ap/Po/Co/Ts/Build -f Build2.mk
    touch $@
```

Target `All` should normally be called `all` and be `.PHONY`:

```
.PHONY: all All
```

Comment: Thank you all , Actually , make targets are generated at bottom level of make file but we planned to restrict make to not get into that level if there is no changes in prerequisites.Now we have added this line "touch c1 c2 c3 c4 c5" on last command of top level make file recipe. now it is working. Thank you very much all.